# How to combine multiple Redux Saga calls

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

How do I combine 2 saga calls that I need to use separately on other pages?

I have tried a few things (yield all, etc) based on other SO answers but I am unable to achieve the desired result.

I have the saga shown below and my app mostly works fine. On the individual Collections and Collection page I have no issues. However, I have a page that is a combination of Collections and a Collection. After Collections are returned, my Saga sets setLoader to false BEFORE the 2nd saga call returns results for Collection meaning my loader does not behave correctly.

I am sure I could add another duck/middleware for GET_BOTH, *loadBoth could be done but I want to avoid that.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import { fork, call, put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setLoader } from "../ducks/loader";
import { types as collectionsTypes, actions as collectionsActions } from "../ducks/collections";
import { types as collectionTypes, actions as collectionActions } from "../ducks/collection";
import { 
    getCollectionsApiRequest,
    getCollectionApiRequest
} from "../services/api";

export function* loadInitialCollections(query = "") {
    try {
        yield put(setLoader(true));
        const collectionsResult = yield call(getCollectionsApiRequest, query);

        yield put(collectionsActions.getCollectionsSuccess({
            collections: collectionsResult.data,
            feature: collectionsTypes.COLLECTIONS
        }));
        yield put(setLoader(false));

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

export function* loadInitialCollection(query = "") {
    try {
        yield put(setLoader(true));
        const collectionResult = yield call(getCollectionApiRequest, query);

        yield put(collectionActions.getCollectionSuccess({
            collection: collectionResult.data,
            feature: collectionTypes.COLLECTION
        }));
        yield put(setLoader(false));

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


export function* watchGetCollectionsRequest() {
    while(true) {
        const { query } = yield take(collectionsTypes.GET_COLLECTIONS);
        yield fork(loadInitialCollections, query);
    }
}

export function* watchGetCollectionRequest() {
    while(true) {
        const { query } = yield take(collectionTypes.GET_COLLECTION);
        yield fork(loadInitialCollection, query);
    }
}

const salesSaga = [
    fork(watchGetCollectionsRequest),
    fork(watchGetCollectionRequest)
];

export default salesSaga;
```

Comment: I am guessing I did combine calls correctly with my yield all attempt but setLoader will always unset Loader too early cos its in both calls. Should I move setLoader out of calls somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `put` on an action `collectionActions.getCollectionSuccess`, you can call saga what is resolve by action directly using `call`, thanks that it will wait unit saga `getCollectionSuccess` will be finished.

Comment: Yep, thanks Piotr. I appreciate you taking time to respond to my question. 

I thought I had tried that but I guess I didnt split the `yield put(setLoader(true))` into `yield call(setLoader, true)`

Comment: Can someone send a code snippet I don't get the answer